# Prove that if a sequence of harmonic function on the open disk converges uniformlyon compact subset of the disk，then the limit is harmonic.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, compactness

I let {${u_n}$}is a sequence of harmonic functions defined on an open disk and $|u_n|≤M$,where {$u_n$}satisfying $u_n(x)$→$u(x)$ for a.e.$x$ as n tends to infinity.

And then I can't think of any way in complex analysis that I can keep doing this problem, so I'm going to use the formula I learned in real analysis, right

$$\int u(x)dx＝lim_{n→∞}\int u_n(
x)dx$$

But then I don't know how to use the harmonic function and the compact set and who can give me a little help, thank you very much

Comment: Do you know the Poisson kernel?

Comment: I just went and looked at it, and I think I can take a circle of radius R inside an open disk and then that disk is a compact set, and then I can apply Poisson's kernel to it，thank you